# Using NodeIterator (Or TreeWalker) with MutationObservers

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I'm using mutation observers to monitor changes to the DOM, and I have a NodeIterator that replaces certain text nodes containing text filtered by a regular expression with dynamically created content.

The issue I'm having is that upon the first run through the NodeIterator, the Node Iterator is now pointing at null and it can't run the algorithm against the dynamically inserted content. If I try to reassign it, it hangs up. Why is it hanging up? Is there a solution to this problem?

```
var nodeIterator = document.createNodeIterator(
        document.body,
        NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,
        acceptAlgo,
        false
    );

iterate(nodeIterator);

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    if (mutation.addedNodes) {
      var dynamicNode = document.createNodeIterator(
        mutation.target,
        NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,
        acceptAlgo,
        false
      );
      iterate(dynamicNode);
    }
  });
});


function iterate(iterator) {
    while ((node = iterator.nextNode())) {
        replaceFunction(node);
    }
}

var config = {
  attributes: false,
  childList: true,
  characterData: false,
  subtree: true
};

observer.observe(document.body, config);
```

Comment: 1. Your MutationObserver callback processes the replacement nodes as well, thus creating an infinite loop that hangs the browser 2. Why are you processing `mutation.target` (it could be the entire `document.body`) instead of each of the added nodes?

Comment: I realized this later that evening, but you are definitely correct. Thank you for the reply.